# Get the name of the Mac OS application to use in script

Tags: macos, osascript

I used to force Microsoft Remote Desktop application to quit via a script call:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Remote Desktop Connection" to quit'
```

I think sometimes ago MS might have change the name of the application and this call no longer works.

So my question is: How in general would one find out a name of the application he can refer to from script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at what the Menu bar says when it's frontmost...

[image]

I can't test with your osascript command, as I don't use it on this machine, but from Script Editor
`tell application "Microsoft Remote Desktop" to quit`
works perfectly.

btw, that's not a force-quit, it's just a quit.
Force-quit would be `killall [processname]`